# can you make a call to AudioObjectSetPropertyData be synchronous?

Tags: c++, macos, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, core-audio

I am setting the samplerate of a device using AudioObjectSetPropertyData.

Is there a way to make this call be synchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlikely, as inserting or changing a sample rate converter in a running sample stream can cause serious glitches.  One possible solution is to run your own sample rate converters in parallel and switch between the converters at your desired sample time.  A cross-fade may be required in some cases.